# Silverlight pathlistbox item adding animation

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

i have storyboard to adding items in Pathlistbox. am calling it in loaded event of the path list box. at first page load its works well. when am clearing and adding the items again in PLB i cant see the animation,i tried calling the storyboard while adding the items. even its not working. whats the problem??